# "compiled with gcc" vs "compiled in gcc"

Tags: differences, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

> 1. "This program was compiled **with** gcc."
> 2. "This program was compiled **in** gcc."
> 3. "This program was written **in** C++."
> 4. "This program was written **with** C++."

Note: gcc is a widely used compiler by C/C++ programers.

What are the subtle differences between the pairs of sentences?

Comment: *... compiled **with** gcc* is the more widely used expression.

Comment: @Kris, please review my post. I appended two new sentences.

Comment: Try and not change the question in its scope. You can ask a new question instead.

Comment: Written **in** C, not *with C.  C is a language. You have asked this question **in** English, not *with English, right?

Comment: @Kris, why does "with gcc" is correct while "with c++" is not?

Comment: See my comment above and my answer below.

Comment: You could also say, "compiled using GCC." This implies GCC is a tool for compiling programs.

Answer (score 4):

Neither of your examples is most correct; programs are compiled *by* compilers. GCC is doing the work to compile C code to machine code or whatever.

As for the subtle differences between your examples:

Compiled with is more correct than compiled in but both are awkward compared to the above. Using "with" to say "compiled using" is more appropriate if you are talking about the future:

"We will compile the C-code with GCC"

However, if you are talking about previously compiled code then "compiled by" makes the most sense as the work has been done, and it was performed **by** the compiler.

Finally, since GCC is a thing (ie a piece of software) rather than a place, "compiled in" doesn't make much sense in this case. When talking about building or making something, consider goods like a car being made **in** a specific country. This is why we tend to say that products are "made in China" instead of "made by China."

edit: As pointed out in the comments, we do tend to say that programs are written **IN** languages . Programs aren't written **BY** languages though, because the language is not doing the work, you are! That should also answer the additional sentences you added about writing *IN* C++ and then compiling that code *WITH* GCC to the point where the output was compiled *BY* GCC.

Comment: please review my post. I appended two new sentences.

Comment: I disagree with your last paragraph.  "in" is used for more than just places - for example: ***"This program was written in HTML."***

Comment: @KristinaLopez html is a language (hyperText Markup Language), not a compiler.

Comment: @Kris, My point to Mattacular was that they said "in" was limited to use for a place such as "made in China".  I was pointing out the flaw in *that* statement and my example was to show another use for "in", not to imply that HTML was a compiler.

Comment: We are arguing *in* English, though we may be across the world. :)

Comment: @KristinaLopez - you're right, we do say "in" to mean more than just places. My comments are only pertinent to this context where we are talking about building/making things. I'll update my post.

Answer (score 2):

While the preposition *in* would make more sense and appear to be the natural choice considering the program is compiled in a specific compiler environment, '*compiled **with** gcc*' is the predominant version found in literature.

The probable reasoning could be that gcc is not only a compiler but also a substantial set of libraries and includes.

From the horse's mouth ([gnu.org](http://gcc.gnu.org/)): [emphasis mine]

> GCC, the GNU Compiler **Collection**: The GNU Compiler **Collection** includes front ends for C, C++, Objective-C, Fortran, Java, Ada, and Go, as well as **libraries** for these languages (libstdc++, libgcj,...).

[nGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=compiled%20with%20gcc,compiled%20in%20gcc,%20compiled%20by%20gcc&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image]

Web:
compiled *with* gcc 1,540,000
compiled *by* gcc 547,000
compiled *in* gcc 228,000
Books:
compiled *with* gcc 2,600
compiled *by* gcc 491
compiled *in* 4

Comment: With and by GCC are both correct, depending on the tense/context. Since the examples in the original question are all past-tense, 'compiled by' is most correct. Let's not pretend that programmers are the best writers. Just because the GNU developers are brilliant at writing compilers does not mean they are brilliant at writing english.

Comment: @mattacular Obviously, you've not factored in the includes. And you don't down vote (in case you wanted to) because you don't agree with the answer; you would instead, if you offer an authentic counter to it. No room for opinions in voting.

Comment: @mattacular If developers used the preposition *with*, it's with good reason, not because they are poor in English. This is proved by the fact that they capitalize English. Evidently, they are definitely better than us. :)

Comment: Sorry but my first comment was the authentic counter. Also sorry that I didn't think slapping up an nGram and calling it a day was sufficient to answer the original question which was "what are the subtle differences?" not "how frequently is each used?" Especially since one is correct over the other depending on context/tense I felt it needed more explanation than you provided.

Comment: Also I am genuinely curious why you think this is true: "If developers used the preposition with, it's with good reason, not because they are poor in English" I've never known programmers to be as deliberate or cautious with natural spoken language as they are with machine languages.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answers that *compiled by* is better. I just wanted to give you a more general rule on why sometimes we use *with* and other *by*. Often, it is a case of tense, past vs. future. For example

> I will break the window **with** a hammer.

Once the window has been broken, you could examine it and say

> This window was broken **by** a hammer.

So, for `gcc`, you would say

> I *will* compile the software **with** gcc
>
> The software *was* compiled **by** gcc.